# User authentication failure /w Hash

Tags: hash, passwords, sha1, salt

And I need to secure some area's on my web store for admin use.
The problem is the authentication of the user: the salt + hash is failing.

This is my code for creating a password (using PHP5.x):

```
$salt = rand(0, 999999999999);<br>
$passEncr = sha1($pass1 + $salt);
```

This variable $passEncr is inserted into the database together with its salt.

At the login page I've got the following check:

```
$password = $_POST['password']; // hash+salt in the database

$storedSalt = $row['salt']; // salt from database<br>
if (sha1($password + $storedSalt) == $row['password'])
```

Now the problem I'm experiencing is that some hashes appear to be the same.
If I try to log in with an alphanumeric password, I succeed, no matter what the content of that password is. 
Full login check here: http://pastebin.com/WjVnQ4aF

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, SQL injection, using SHA for passwords instead of bcrypt are the first things I see, not using OpenId so you can get out of the business of storing passwords is another.

As for the passwords being the same, I would check the database -- see what you are storing, that will tell you where your problem lies.